# A condition that causes an enjoyable sensation in the brain when drinking cold beverages

Tags: neurology

Whenever I drink something very cold and direct the flow towards the roof of my mouth close to the brain, I do not get any uncomfortable sensation like many do, on the contrary, I find it highly enjoyable. It feels relaxing and feels like it is affecting my brain somehow. Can I get an explanation, and is this a documented condition?

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing sounds like the human condition, not "a condition".

Eccles and colleagues note (2013. PMID [24060271](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/24060271/)):

> Ingestion of cold products such as ice-lollies and ice cream is perceived as pleasant because of pleasure associated with satiation of thirst and a refreshing effect. Cold is perceived differently in the skin and oral mucosa, leading to different effects on temperature regulation, and perception of pleasure or dis-pleasure, depending on the body temperature and the temperature of the external environment.

Thus, humans are evolved to enjoy cold beverages because it satisfies thirst.  The authors also note the same is true for lower mammals as well. Evolutionary pressures were unable to foresee that we'd suddenly invent refrigeration.